# How to make a label over each set of 2 columns for a heatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation

I'm trying to create a heatmap in RStudio to show correlations between different microbe species and environmental variables, with each environmental variable having two columns, tissue and mucus.

I have the tissue and mucus columns set up but i can't seem to set upo a label for each set of tissue and mucus columns.
This is what it currently looks like.

Heatmap with misplaced labels:

[image]

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(cowplot)

dfmerge <- data

dfmerge$interaction <- with(dfmerge, interaction(Env, Type, sep = " - "))
dfmerge$interaction <- factor(dfmerge$interaction, levels = sort(levels(dfmerge$interaction)))


heatmap_plot <- ggplot(dfmerge, aes(x = interaction, y = Taxa, fill = Correlation)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Observations", title = "Heatmap") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub("^[^-]* - ", "", x), expand = c(0.05, 0))

num_envs <- length(unique(dfmerge$Env))
label_width <- 1 / num_envs

env_labels_df <- dfmerge %>%
  distinct(Env) %>%
  mutate(xpos = (1:length(Env)) * 2 - 1)

env_labels <- ggplot(env_labels_df, aes(x = xpos, y = 1, label = Env)) +
  geom_label(fill = "lightgrey", size = 5, label.padding = unit(0.25, "lines"), label.size = label_width) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.5, num_envs * 2 - 0.5), clip = "off")

heatmap_with_labels <- cowplot::plot_grid(env_labels, heatmap_plot, nrow = 2, rel_heights = c(0.1, 1), align = "h", axis = "tb")

print(heatmap_with_labels)
```

This is what I am trying to emulate:

[heatmap courtesy of "Microbiome dynamics in the tissue and mucus of acroporid corals differ in relation to host and environmental parameters":

[image]

For those wondering, I have to rewrite the code for it, can't just use the image from the paper.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to recreate the plot 'manually' I think you need to make some significant changes, e.g. here is a closer approximation using the built-in "ChickWeights" dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

data("ChickWeight")

palette <- brewer.pal(n = 5, name = "RdBu")

ChickWeight %>%
  mutate(norm = rnorm(n = n(), mean = 200, sd = 50)) %>%
  filter(Time %in% 6:20,
         Chick %in% 30:50) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(weight, norm)) %>%
  mutate(Correlation = 1 - (value / max(value)) - 0.5) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = Chick, fill = Correlation)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~Time, nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = palette) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Alternatively, this figure may have been created by the authors using a package, e.g. corrplot (or something similar) so it might be worth reading the methods section of the paper and/or searching google for similar heatmap figures. Hope this helps :)